# Exposing Docker application to host

Tags: pdf, centos, docker

I wish to run a legacy application which is compatible with centos6 which no longer has some dependencies maintained and therefore is incompatible with centos7. This application is called pdftk.

I want to (if this is remotely possible) run pdftk within a docker image of centos6 and expose this application to centos7...

The app does a couple of things:

Takes a PDF document as input & form data as input -> fills the PDF with the form data -> outputs the filled in PDF.

The command might look a little like this:

```
pdftk input.pdf --do-something output.pdf
```

Would something like this be possible with docker?

So far I have been able to initialise a centos6 image and successfully install pdftk. Any help with the next part (again if possible) would be most appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Hi Daniel - would you mind sharing your Dockerfile? I don't think that pdftk can be installed via yum by default, so the Dockerfile below doesn't quite work for me. Great workaround to an annoying problem, btw. Thanks!

Comment: here you go: 

http://pastebin.com/xerEiq52

Comment: Perfect. Really appreciate it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can write a Dockerfile with Centos6 as base, then install pdftk and any other dependency. Finally use Dockerfile command `ENTRYPOINT` to set the pdftk as the command of your image, and pass it the arguments you wish. For example (I haven't tested it, it's only an example):

```
FROM centos:centos6
RUN yum install pdftk
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/bin/pdftk"]
```

Then you can build this image. Supposed you call it 'pdftk', you could run the container as: `docker run -it --rm pdftk <arguments>` -> `docker run -it --rm -v ~/my_pdfs:/pdfs pdftk /pdfs/input.pdf --do-something /pdfs/output.pdf`

Comment: Yes thank you, I worked out something alone the lines of your solution, I did not know about the entrypont command.